# How to figure out if my engine is locked or the cam and crank shaft sensors need replaced on 02 Honda civic lx

Tags: honda

I have a 02 Honda civic lx my engine light had kept blinking on and off for a couple of days I knew it needed an oil change and had to wait until I got paid but I had my boyfriend check to make sure there was enough oil in it to male it he said it was thin but there was enough. While driving home my car seemed like it ran out of gas.put gas in it and the car wouldn't turn over I replaced the starter and still the car was clicking like it wanted to try and start but would not turn over checked battery, starter, ECT. My bf checked the oil again and it wasn't even reading on the dipstick and I have no oil leak. My bf thinks the engine is locked because the fly wheel won't turn could it just be a sensor

Comment: edit:  oops posted my answer here by mistake

Comment: Does the car have a manual or automatic gearbox?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it sounds like the engine has either partially or fully seized up.

Answer (score 0):

**Main point**:  You should NEVER ignore a red light as that light is reserved for stuff that goes wrong with the car that can damage it irreparably.
**secondary point**:  There is no sensor that will stop the engine cranking.
**Lesser point**: The dipstick only reads two quarts maximum and that depends on the car.

It is possible for someone with the right tools to see if the engine is locked up.  You simply have to put a breaker-bar and socket on the main pulley and try to rotate the engine clockwise.  Ensure the car is in neutral for this.  If you are able to move it (and it takes a fair bit of strength) then the motor is not locked up.  This is a lot easier to do with the spark plugs out.

The lead-up to the stop gives me this opinion on what happened to your car (and i'm only about 50% sure so it may be something else)
1) "oil looked thin" "no oil leaks" "oil is missing" These three things make me think you have a broken ring.  Gas is leaking past the broken ring and mixing with the oil.  Now the oil becomes much thinner because it's mixed with gas.  It can then be burned during the running of the engine by slipping by the valve guides.  Remember this is conjecture.  This would explain loss of oil level.  Now, gas-laden oil is not good for lubricating, and oil in your car actually serves two purposes:  It lubricates and it keeps the lower-end of the motor cool.  So poor lubrication will cause the lower-end of the motor to eventually overheat, as well as doing major damage to every moving part in the engine.
Coupling this conjecture with "car slowed down like it was running out of gas" is exactly what happens when an engine overheats, and the low-end could be red hot but the thermostat wouldn't know it since it's in the radiator.  Maybe it's not seized, but the coincidences all line up to make it seem like it is.

Still, i would have a real mechanic look at it.  **You could also get the "dying and won't crank now" just from a dead battery.**